# Wordpress Multisite SMTP not working on other network sites

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have WP Mail SMTP plugin setup on multisite, the email is sent from the parent site successfully, however, when trying the same or another email from the child site gives me following error:

```
ErrorInfo: The following From address failed: info@example.com : MAIL FROM command failed,RNPI Access denied by login ip protect
,550,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: RNPI Access denied by login ip protect
SMTP code: 550SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: RNPI Access denied by login ip protect
SMTP code: 550
```

Can someone suggest me how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Either the SMTP server is using white listing and the IP of the child site is NOT listed or it is using black listing and the IP of the child site IS listed.  I'm not aware of any other reasons for this error.

Comment: I'm using AWS EC2 instance, it's Bitnami Wordpress Multisite stack.